# JavaScript document.execCommand remove formatBlock formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, contenteditable

If I format a piece of text on a page like this:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'h1');
```

What do I do to remove this formatting?

Comment: Is undo an option? `document.execCommand("Undo", false, null)`

Comment: Unfortunately undo is not an option, because this may be executed multiple times on different elements, and is partially user controlled, and I don't want to be undoing all the changes in between.

Comment: Fair enough. I think your options are limited to manual DOM manipulation then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<strike>I suppose `document.execCommand('removeFormat',false,false)` would do it?</strike>

Issuing `document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div')` on the `<h1>`-block will remove the `<h1>`-tag and replace it with a `<div>`-tag <sup>**1**</sup>. Would that be viable?

<sup>**1**</sup> If you're not using IE that is

Comment: It doesn't. It removes formatting such as bold, italic, underline, etc. but not HTML tags.

Comment: Apart from the not very well documented and not IE-supported `RemoveParaFormat`, I couldn't think of any `execCommand` that removes  html from a selection. Maybe a regular expression should do the trick?

Comment: Is there generally a problem with having many unused `div` tags floating around randomly? If not, this should be fine.

Comment: I don't think it's much of a problem. The divs aren't really unused I suppose, the text you're clicking on within the contentEditable element is surrounded with a div tag (effectively replacing the previously assigned tag), that's all. Every new line you make in a contentEditable element is wrapped in a div too.

Answer (score 3):

I clear the effect of h1 using this:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
```

You have changed its format to h1, so we can change it back to normal paragraph format in the same way.
If your put each paragraph in a  <div> , you can also use this:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
```

to set the format to the same as other blocks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem where I need to delete the h1 tag wrapping my text.

What I did was get the parent node of the selected text:

> var elem_parent_node =
>   window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;

And then check if it's nodeName is "H1"; if yes, then store the selected text in a selected_text variable and then delete the node itself:

> elem_parent_node.remove();

Then,

> document.execCommand('insertText', false, select_text);

Answer (score 1):

To replace the h1 with its text content node, then use the code below.
For a complete code, you would need to add some checks to make sure you remove what you want.

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
    selection.anchorNode.parentNode.replaceWith(selection.anchorNode)
  }
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h1>Select me then click the button</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<button>Click to remove H1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Proposed solutions above are feasible, although they don't proof against the parent beeing the conteneditable-container (div?), so this could potentially remove/destroy the writable area.
A bit safer workaround for this issue may be to replace the "formatBlock" with a less used one, as f.ex. <address> and then remove this <address> with a regexp-replacer:

```
function Header() { //formatBlock: "h1"-"h6", "p", "pre", "div", "dd", "dt" or unformat it(=empty) - except using "address" (⇓see⇓)
var Fo = prompt('Please enter: h1-h6(=number), p, pre, ...','1');
if (Number(Fo)) {
    Fo = 'h' + Fo; //format with h1-h6 directly by entering numbers - or p, pre, etc...
    document.execCommand('formatblock', false, Fo);
} else if (Fo=='') { //if let empty, then unformat the block:
    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'address'); //using "address" as a temporary substitute - hoping that it's not used anywhere else in the document...
    let inner = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML; //internal code of document
    inner = inner.replace(/<address>/g,'<br>').replace(/n\n\n|\n\n|\n\s/g,'\n'); //Regex deleting (all) <address>-headings (and spaces) from document, replacing them with a line-break
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = inner; //restore the content with replaced paragraph's
} else { document.execCommand('formatblock', false, Fo) }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you may have to find the parent tag, then use innerHTML to get the text and replace the original data between the parent tag and end-tag with the innerHTML. This would however remove all formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you cannot "undo" a formatBlock. You can always replace one "formatBlock" with some other "formatBlock" as long as it is another block level HTML tag.