# How do I programmatically remove <H1>~<H6> tags?

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, webview, html-heading

I'm currently Working on a OSX Application, which uses a editable WebView.
I use a

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"FormatBlock\", false, \"<H1>\")"];
```

command to give the selected paragraph(or the paragraph where the cursor is located) a H1 tag.
Is there a way to remove the < H1 >~< H6 > (And if possible < Blockquote >) tags?
Even better, Is there a way to change the tags into a < div > tag instead?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a similar question at [JavaScript document.execCommand remove formatBlock formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810940/javascript-document-execcommand-remove-formatblock-formatting)

All I needed to do was

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"FormatBlock\", false, \"<div>\")"];
```